# EventListener mostrando documentos que no existen - Firebase

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-snapshot

Me podrían por favor decir si esto es posible:

Estoy liado con un `EventListener` que al dispararse la primera vez (primera vez al iniciar la app, no primera vez en el dia) me esta mostrando en `Documents` y en `DocumentChanges` elementos que fueron eliminados el dia de ayer, lo que causa que al intentar leer los IDs que estan en Documents me de error.

Revise la Coleccion al que esta enlazado el Listener y efectivamente no estan esos docs. De hecho, actualmente en la coleccion solo tengo 13 resultados y me esta cargando 16.

**Listener:**

[image: 1]

**Coleccion con 13 registros:**

[image: 2]

**Resultado del Snapshot en OnEvent con 16 registros (iniciando desde 0):**

[image: 3]

Comment: Cuál es el mensaje de error?  Estás seguro de que es por leer el id? Es normal que la primera vez lea los datos del cache pero de todos modos deberías poder obtener su id

Comment: Es que si obtengo el Id. El problema es que es un registro que ya no existe dado que se borro ayer. (En mi opinion e inexperiencia creo que no me deberia de cargar Ids que no estan en la coleccion) Pero ya voy entendiendo que lee los datos del cache. Siendo asi lo que intentare es ejecutar el metodo hasta que vaya a realizar algun cambio en la coleccion para que los Ids que me muestre si esten en la coleccion (y omita los eliminados)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el listener la primera vez lee los datos del cache para poder mostrar un resultado inmediato sin que el usuario tenga que esperar la respuesta del servidor. Si no es lo que deseas, puedes usar el método [isFromCache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata#isFromCache()) para detectar e ignorar los resultados que vengan del cache.

```
if (!data.Metadata.IsFromCache)
{
    var serverDocuments = data.Documents;
}
```

Para que esto funcione debes incluir la metadata en el momento que agregues el listener

```
.AddSnapshotListener(MetadataChanges.Include, this);
```

Comment: Uff! Super util, me funciono excelente. Te lo agradezco. En Xamarin.Android me quedo de esta forma:  --    if (!data.Metadata.IsFromCache)
{
    var serverDocuments = data.Documents;
}         --         AddSnapshotListener(MetadataChanges.Include, this);    --

Comment: gracias por corregirme. La verdad es que no conozco xamarin pero de todos modos intento ayudar. Ahora mismo estoy escribiendo una respuesta a otra de tus preguntas